# Drupal 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal, http-status-code-301

I am doing a set of 301 redirects in Drupal.

I am using a standard method in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /user/testimonials http://thesitedomain.com/testimonials
Redirect 301 /user/contact http://thesitedomain.com/contact
</IfModule>
```

but the return url ends up with "?q=user" and stops it working. eg:

```
http://thesitedomain.com/about?q=user/about
```

I am not great at htaccess redirects (obviously) and I am no Drupal expert at all.

Also, if you know of a comprehensive htaccess rewrite resource I would much appreciate reading hat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `mod_rewrite` instead to strip out existing query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/testimonials/?$ http://thesitedomain.com/testimonials? [L,NC,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^user/contact/?$ http://thesitedomain.com/contact? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Take note of trailing `?` in target that strips out existing query string.

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately... It just goes to the same page: /user/testimonials/

Comment: Make sure this 301 rule is **very first rule** in your root .htaccess and you test in a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to drupal, but I know you don't need to enclose those redirects in the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tags, since they don't use the `RewriteEngine`, the below would suffice:

```
Redirect 301 /user/testimonials http://thesitedomain.com/testimonials
Redirect 301 /user/contact http://thesitedomain.com/contact
```

Answer (score 0):

Are both urls in the same drupal? Or are you moving from a different site?
I mean:

- /user/testimonials
- http://thesitedomain.com/testimonials

Maybe what you need is to add an url alias for /user/testimonials like /testimonials

See under admin at /admin/config/search/path in drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess file is not a good practice, because, in some updates you have to update the .htaccess file too.

You can try [GlobalRedirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module to manage your redirects.